# escape html tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i have issue with using autoescape django template tag here is my code

```
msg="&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location. &lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Marriott Dallas Addison Quorum Galleria is located in Dallas&apos;s Addison - Galleria neighborhood, close to Galleria Dallas, Cavanaugh Flight Museum, and Northwood Club. Additional area points of interest include University of Texas at Dallas. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Hotel Features. &lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Dining options at Marriott Dallas Addison Quorum Galleria include a restaurant and a coffee shop/café. A bar/lounge is open for drinks. Room service is available. The hotel serves buffet breakfasts (surcharges apply). Recreational amenities include an outdoor pool, an indoor pool, and a spa tub. This 3.5-star property has a business center and offers small meeting rooms, limo/town car service, and audio-visual equipment. Wireless Internet access (surcharge) is available in public areas. The property offers a roundtrip airport shuttle (surcharge).  Guest parking is available for a surcharge. Additional property amenities include a concierge desk, gift shops/newsstands, and ATM/banking services. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Guestrooms. &lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt; 547 air-conditioned guestrooms at Marriott Dallas Addison Quorum Galleria feature coffee/tea makers and complimentary newspapers. Wired high-speed and wireless Internet access is available for a surcharge. In addition to desks, guestrooms offer multi-line phones with voice mail. Televisions have premium cable channels and pay movies. Rooms also include hair dryers and irons/ironing boards. A turndown service is available nightly, housekeeping is offered daily, and guests may request wake-up calls. &lt;/p&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Notifications and Fees:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The following fees and deposits are charged by the property at time of service, check-in, or check-out.  &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Self parking fee: USD 12 per day&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Valet parking fee: USD 17 per day&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fee for wireless Internet in public areas: USD 3.95 per day (rates may vary)&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Fee for in-room high-speed Internet (wired): USD 12.95 per day (rates may vary)&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fee for in-room wireless Internet: USD 12.95 per day (rates may vary)&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Buffet breakfast fee: USD 17 per person (approximate amount)&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The above list may not be comprehensive. Fees and deposits may not include tax and are subject to change. &lt;/p&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Notifications and Fees:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The following fees and deposits are charged by the property at time of service, check-in, or check-out.  &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Self parking fee: USD 12 per day&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Valet parking fee: USD 17 per day&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fee for wireless Internet in public areas: USD 3.95 per day (rates may vary)&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Fee for in-room high-speed Internet (wired): USD 12.95 per day (rates may vary)&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fee for in-room wireless Internet: USD 12.95 per day (rates may vary)&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Buffet breakfast fee: USD 17 per person (approximate amount)&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The above list may not be comprehensive. Fees and deposits may not include tax and are subject to change. &lt;/p&gt;"

{% autoescape off %}{{msg}}{% endautoescape %}
```

but it still showing html tags?

Comment: That's not "code". What do you mean by that `msg=` line? I suppose that it is the supposed string value of the template variable?  And what do you mean by "showing html tags"? How does it appear? How do you want it to appear?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{% filter escape %} msg {% endfilter %}
```

or you may need to use force_escape filter, depending on the situation

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally follow you but have you tried

```
{{ msg|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to put your html content in some variable and do not want it escaped in the template and want it to be used as normal html. In that case,

```
msg = "<p>Location</p>"
{% autoescape off %}{{msg}}{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your escaped text is coming from a field in a model (or in another way coming from the backend), you can (in addition to what people have already said) use `mark_safe` within your Python code, rather doing anything in the template. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

Let's say a field in a model is consistently populated with characters that will be autoescaped: you may want to add a method to the model that returns the value marked as safe. For example:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Something(models.Model):
    html_text = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #...

    def get_html(self):
        return mark_safe(self.html_text)
```

Then in your template you just use `{{ my_something.get_html }}`